# Cannot find module error when importing local font .otf file into typescript project

Tags: typescript, fonts

I'm trying to import a local font into my React/Typescript project.

The font file, `Averta-Cyrillic_Regular.otf`, is placed in the `src/assets/fonts/` folder.

Inside the same folder is a `fonts.d.ts` file with just a single line:

```
declare module '*.otf'
```

And my `tsconfig.json` file has the following include rule:

```
"include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"]
```

So technically it should be able to import fine?

However, when I try to import the font in `src/assets/fonts/fonts.ts` like below:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

import AvertaCyrillicRegular from './Averta-Cyrillic_Regular.otf'

export default createGlobalStyle`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Averta Cyrillic Regular';
        src: local('Averta Cyrillic Regular'), local('AvertaCyrillicRegular'),
        url(${AvertaCyrillicRegular}) format('otf'),
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
    },
`
```

It throws the following error:

```
Cannot find module './Averta-Cyrillic_Regular.otf' or its corresponding type declarations.  TS2307

    1 | import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'
    2 |
  > 3 | import AvertaCyrillicRegular from './Averta-Cyrillic_Regular.otf'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a declaration in the .d.ts file of our project with the extension of the font files.

`declare module "*.woff2"`